# Can I use SQL Server tools (like Management Studio, profiler) on any number of computers?

Tags: sql-server, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

We have bought SQL Server Enterprise version.

Can we install client tools on any number of computers to connect to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you have the per processor license for SQL Server. You'll need a CAL for each client if you bought server/CAL licenses though (either per device or per user).

Edit about CALs: You do not need CALs for:

1. any of your servers licensed or and running instances of the server software, and
2. up to two devices or users to access your instances of the server software only to administer those instances.) .

See also http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/get-sql-server/how-to-buy.aspx